# Extraction of an Oracle table in Pentaho

Tags: oracle, pentaho, oracle12c, pentaho-data-integration

When I try to extract a table from Oracle database to Pentaho, there's no result. I get the following message:

[image]

Comment: Message :: Sorry , no data is retrned for previsulation

Comment: well. if you execute the query in some sql tool - does it return anything? if query return nothing the message can be correct

Comment: no it return tuples.

Comment: This step error is given for several different errors. In the connection setup, is the Test connection returning Ok ? Is the connection connecting in the correct Host/Database. A lot of things are "hidden" when you use an SQL tool, some of these details have to be expressed in ETL.